# Trouble parsing out mixed keyvalue and JSON in Datadog Grok parser

Tags: logging, datadog, grok

I'm trying to parse Datadog logs that have a mixed format.

I have some logs coming to Datadog that look like this:

```
... some_field="value123" org_id="test-org-id" query_params="{"updated_date": {"eq": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z", "lte": "2025-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, "active": {"eq": true}}" request_id="test-request-id" request_method="GET" ... Response: {"data": []}
```

I've so far been parsing them using the following rules in the Grok parser:

```
rule ...%{some_field}?%{org_id}?%{query_params}?%{request_id}?%{request_method}?...%{regex(".*"):msg}
org_id (%{regex("org_id=")}\"%{regex("[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+"):org_id}\"\s)
query_params (%{regex("query_params=")}\"%{regex("\\{.*\\}"):query_params}\"\s)
request_id (%{regex("request_id=")}\"%{regex("[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-\\=]+"):request_id}\"\s)
request_method (%{regex("request_method=")}\"%{regex("[a-zA-Z]+"):request_method}\"\s)
```

and here's what the output looks like:

```
{
  "msg": "Response: {"data": []}",
  "request_method": "GET",
  "org_id": "test-org-id",
  "query_params": "{\"updated_date\": {\"eq\": \"2020-01-01T00:00:00Z\", \"lte\": \"2025-01-01T00:00:00Z\"}, \"active\": {\"eq\": true}}",
  "request_id": "test-request-id"
}
```

I'd like to:

1. have the query params parsed as JSON so they could come out like this

   1. ```
      {
        "msg": "Response: {"data": []}",
        "request_method": "GET",
        "org_id": "test-org-id",
        "query_params": {
              "updated_date": {
                  "eq": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                  "lte": "2025-01-01T00:00:00Z"
              },
              "active": true
        }
        "request_id": "test-request-id"
      }
      ```
2. get any advice on simplifying my master rule. I've tried something like this:

   1. ```
      api_rule %{celery_prefix}?\s*%{data::keyvalue}?%{query_params}?%{data::keyvalue}?%{regex("Response: .*"):msg}
      ```

      but it threw away the data from query_params for some reason.

I have control over the way the logs come out, so if anything needs to be changed from the backend that's also an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved with some help from the great folks at Datadog support.

```
updated_api_rule %{regex(".+?(?=query_params)")::keyvalue}query_params="%{regex("\\{.*\\}"):query_params:json}%{regex(".+?(?=Response)")::keyvalue}%{data:msg}
```